# Multiple IF Statements in catch block rollback

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, transactions, try-catch

I need some help!

I have a stored procedure with try/catch block.  It works fine but when I try and test by putting in values that should hit the catch block, it doesn't seem to do it.  Is there something wrong with my catch block that it's not rolling back the transaction?  Like bad data is being put into the DB that even though it shouldn't.  What am I doing wrong?? Thank you, in advance!

```
begin try 
Begin Transaction
Insert Into ProcessingRequestQueue(PRQID,PRQTarget, PRQStatus, PRQCommand, PRQCDSRNO)
Values (newid(),'CARDSIEVER','I',@PRQCommand,@cdsrno)
commit
End Try

Begin Catch 
IF (@cdsrno = 0 and (@cdsrno is null or @cdsrno = ''))

or (@PRQCommand is null or @PRQCommand = '')
rollback


End Catch 
END
```

Answer (score 0):

The catch only works if the `INSERT` has exception, in your query there are 2 possible cases to raise the exception, otherwise the `CATCH` **NEVER** be reached.

1. You have primary key on PRQID and the NEWID() generate a duplicate value (which is unlikely to happen)
2. You have unique index on PRQCommand or PRQCDSRNO and you supply non null value to it which already exists in the table

The better way to do is putting the variable check before the insert, then rollback without any condition.

Comment: Oh man, you're right!  I forgot the basics of how the try/catches work!  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
 BEGIN TRY 
INSERT ProcessingRequestQueue(PRQID,PRQTarget, PRQStatus, PRQCommand, PRQCDSRNO)
Values (newid(),'CARDSIEVER','I',@PRQCommand,@cdsrno)
IF @cdsrno = 0 OR @cdsrno is null or @cdsrno = '' or @PRQCommand is null or @PRQCommand = ''
BEGIN<br>
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END
BEGIN CATCH
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END CATCH
```